# module compiling : asm/linkage.h file not found

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to compile an example of "hello world" Kernel Module,
problems found on ubuntu 11.04, kernel 3.2.6, gcc 4.5.2 and fedora 16, kernel 3.2.7, gcc 4.6.7.

code:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static int __init hello_init (void)
{
printk("Hello module init\n");
return 0;
}
static void __exit hello_exit (void)
{
printk("Hello module exit\n");
}
module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

compiled with:

```
gcc -D__KERNEL__ -I /usr/src/linux/include/ -DMODULE -Wall -O2 -c hello.c -o hello.o
```

error:

> In file included from /usr/src/linux/include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
>                    from /usr/src/linux/include/linux/cache.h:4,
>                    from /usr/src/linux/include/linux/time.h:7,
>                    from /usr/src/linux/include/linux/stat.h:60,
>                    from /usr/src/linux/include/linux/module.h:10,
>                    from hello.c:1: /usr/src/linux/include/linux/linkage.h:5:25: fatal error:
>   asm/linkage.h: file not found

then I found in /usr/src/linux/include/ there is no folder named 'asm' but 'asm-generic';
so I made a soft link 'asm' to 'asm-generic', and compiled agail:

this time the error was:

> In file included from /usr/src/linux/include/linux/preempt.h:9:0,
>                    from /usr/src/linux/include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
>                    from /usr/src/linux/include/linux/seqlock.h:29,
>                    from /usr/src/linux/include/linux/time.h:8,
>                    from /usr/src/linux/include/linux/stat.h:60,
>                    from /usr/src/linux/include/linux/module.h:10,
>                    from hello.c:1: /usr/src/linux/include/linux/thread_info.h:53:29: fatal error:
>   asm/thread_info.h: file not found

So I realized I was wrong, but why ? T_T

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
obj-m += hello.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

is a proper way to build modules see  [kbuild documentation](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt)

And to see difference beetween your compiler invocation you could

```
cat /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/Makefile
```

And analyze an output

Comment: How can this Makefile be added to cmake? (CMakeFiles.txt)

Answer (score 4):

```
obj-m += hello.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Here hello.c is your kernel source file. just use make to build your hello.ko module.

Comment: i know this could work, but why it doesn't work in my way? "gcc -D__KERNEL__ -I /usr/src/linux/include/ -DMODULE -Wall -O2 -c hello.c -o hello.o"

Answer (score 1):

`asm` should be a link to the actual architecture you're compiling for, not to `asm-generic`.
You can't compile a generic kernel module, that would work on a generic architecture. You have to compile it for the particular architecture you're going to use.

I don't know why the `asm` didn't exist. It should be created as part of the configuration process.
You might get other errors later, if configuration is incomplete in other ways.

Comment: I've check the kernel src folders(3.2+) on 3 machines with ubuntu, fedora and gentoo, all of them do not contain folder 'asm'. So I think it may not an error..

Comment: In the Redhat I checked, `/usr/src/kernels/.../include/asm` is a link to `asm-x86_64`.

Answer (score 0):

The *asm* includes (such as linkage.h) are architecture specific. There should be a set of directories under:

```
    /usr/src/kernels/(kernel version goes here)/arch
```

that provide specific includes for the specific CPU architecture you are targeting your code to be compiled for.

Try adding this to your Makefile:

```
    KVERSION :=R(shell uname -r)
```

and add the kernel and architecture (x86 in this example):

```
    INCDIRS = -I./include -I/usr/src/kernels/$(KVERSION)/include -I/usr/src/kernels/$(KVERSION)/arch/x86
```

Answer (score -1):

**module compiling : asm/linkage.h file not found**

This means this particular file was not found in specified DIR, which gets specified when we use -I option with make.

We can either link that asm-generic to asm, if all headers are present in asm-generic, or we can use **make utility**.

Make utility is preferred in case of building kernel modules.

Create a 'Makefile' in working DIR.

```
obj-m += hello.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

*Use of -C option will change to DIR specified before reading the makefiles or doing anything else.*

So to avoid this error, use -C option with DIR`/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build`

By this your program will be able to find required files, you will get `hello.ko` file.

You can add this to kernel modules by

```
sudo insmod hello.ko
```

Similarly you can remove by

```
sudo rmmod hello
```