# fatal error: asm/linkage.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, nginx, centos, keep-alive

I need to setp Keepalived To Provide IP Failover For Web Cluster in nginx webserver.

I Follow this link to install keepalive :  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-centos-fedora-keepalived-lvs-cluster-configuration/

While install

```
  $ make && make install
```

system throw    **fatal error: asm/linkage.h**: No such file or directory

This is All error:

```
   [root@www keepalived-1.1.19]# make && make install 
    make -C lib || exit 1;
    make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/keepalived-1.1.19/lib'
    make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/keepalived-1.1.19/lib'
    make -C keepalived
    make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/keepalived-1.1.19/keepalived'
    make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/keepalived-1.1.19/keepalived/core'
    make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/keepalived-1.1.19/keepalived/core'
    make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/keepalived-1.1.19/keepalived/vrrp'
    gcc -g -O2  -I/lib/modules/3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64/build/include -I../include -I../../lib -Wall -Wunused -Wstrict-prototypes -D_KRNL_2_2_ -D_WITHOUT_LVS_ -D_WITHOUT_IPVS_SYNCD_  -c vrrp_daemon.c
    In file included from /lib/modules/3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64/build/include/linux/kernel.h:6:0,
                     from /lib/modules/3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64/build/include/linux/skbuff.h:17,
                     from /lib/modules/3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64/build/include/linux/if_ether.h:23,
                     from /usr/include/net/ethernet.h:26,
                     from ../include/vrrp_arp.h:27,
                     from vrrp_daemon.c:26:
    /lib/modules/3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64/build/include/linux/linkage.h:7:25: fatal error: asm/linkage.h: No such file or directory
     #include <asm/linkage.h>
                             ^
    compilation terminated.
    make[2]: *** [vrrp_daemon.o] Error 1
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/keepalived-1.1.19/keepalived/vrrp'
    make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/keepalived-1.1.19/keepalived'
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    [root@www keepalived-1.1.19]#
```

**Update:**

After folow [module compiling : asm/linkage.h file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492559/module-compiling-asm-linkage-h-file-not-found) this link

I add

^Iobj-m += vrrp_daemon.o

all:  ^I$(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules $

clean: ^I$(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean $

Now, also throw Same Error

This is My Make File:

```
        # Makefile
        #
        # Keepalived OpenSource project.
        #
        # Copyright (C) 2001-2009 Alexandre Cassen, <acassen@linux-vs.org>

        TARFILES = AUTHOR bin ChangeLog configure configure.in CONTRIBUTORS COPYING \
                   doc genhash INSTALL install-sh keepalived keepalived.spec.in lib Makefile.in \
                   README TODO VERSION

        TARBALL = keepalived-1.1.19.tar.gz

        ^Iobj-m += vrrp_daemon.o

        all:    
                $(MAKE) -C lib || exit 1;
                $(MAKE) -C keepalived
                $(MAKE) -C genhash $
                ^I$(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules $
                @echo ""
                @echo "Make complete"

        debug:
                $(MAKE) -C lib || exit 1;
                $(MAKE) -C keepalived debug
                @echo ""
                @echo "Make complete"

        profile:
                $(MAKE) -C lib || exit 1;
                $(MAKE) -C keepalived profile
                @echo ""
                @echo "Make complete"


        clean:
                $(MAKE) -C lib clean
                $(MAKE) -C keepalived clean
                $(MAKE) -C genhash clean
                ^I$(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean $

        distclean:
                $(MAKE) -C lib distclean
                $(MAKE) -C keepalived distclean
                $(MAKE) -C genhash distclean
                rm -f Makefile
                rm -f keepalived.spec

        mrproper: distclean
                rm -f config.*

        uninstall:
                $(MAKE) -C keepalived uninstall
                $(MAKE) -C genhash uninstall

        install:
                $(MAKE) -C keepalived install
                $(MAKE) -C genhash install

        tarball: mrproper
                mkdir keepalived-1.1.19
                cp -a $(TARFILES) keepalived-1.1.19
                tar --exclude .git -czf $(TARBALL) keepalived-1.1.19
                rm -rf keepalived-1.1.19

        rpm:
                rpmbuild -ba keepalived.spec
```

**Update:1**  I find linkage.h file is there...

```
    ./modules/3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64/build/arch/x86/include/asm/linkage.h
    ./modules/3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64/build/include/asm-generic/linkage.h
    ./modules/3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64/build/include/linux/linkage.h
    ./modules/3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64/source/arch/x86/include/asm/linkage.h
    ./modules/3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64/source/include/asm-generic/linkage.h
    ./modules/3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64/source/include/linux/linkage.h
    ./modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/build/arch/x86/include/asm/linkage.h
    ./modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/build/include/asm-generic/linkage.h
    ./modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/build/include/linux/linkage.h
    ./modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/source/arch/x86/include/asm/linkage.h
    ./modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/source/include/asm-generic/linkage.h
    ./modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/source/include/linux/linkage.h
```

Suggest me How to solve this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9492559/1606345

Comment: @AlterMann I update My question. Still I have same problem.

Comment: did you try `find -L -name linkage.h`?

Comment: @Aif  I update My Question Yes , I Find linkage.h file is there.

Comment: I don't know how `asm/` is aliased to `asm-generic` in the build process of the kernel. A quick&dirty way would be to copy the file in the include path, to figure out whether it gets included and the error disappears.